# Prevent "flicker" of states when using shared_preferences

Tags: flutter

I'm loading values with the package shared_preferences and wonder if I can prevent Flutter from using a Future and maybe set the state of the Switch controller before it renders?

Like in the HTML world I would set state in the DOMContentLoaded event callback before rendering of the webpage but in Flutter I don't know if that's possible or how I do it.

```
Future<void> storeValueBool(String name, bool value) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setBool(name, value);
}

class _StartPageState extends State<StartPage> {
bool? _rememberMe;

Future<void> getSharedPrefs() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  setState(() {
    _rememberMe = prefs.getBool("RememberMe");
  });
}

@override 
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _rememberMe = false;
  getSharedPrefs();
}

}
```

And the Switch looks like this:

```
Switch(
   value: _rememberMe ?? false,
   onChanged: (value) => {
   setState(() {
    _rememberMe = value;
    storeValueBool("RememberMe", value);
  })},
  activeColor: customMaterialColor("48A69D")
)
```

First the Switch is Disabled and after the Future is done (I guess) the Switch is set to Enabled:

(You can also see the same behavior with the TextField and the stored value 123)
[image]

Comment: Can you include `storeValueBool`, full widget structure will help better

Comment: sorry yeah I've added it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the value to load before showing the page you can use a FutureBuilder on top the entire page and wait for the future before showing any of the UI elements. That way it won't flicker any elements as the value update when loaded.

You can show a CircularProgressIndicator, a blank screen or whatever while it's loading.

Example:

```
FutureBuilder<bool>(
        future: getFuture(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                Text('Header'),
                TextField(),
                Switch(value: snapshot.data ?? false, onChanged: changeValue),
              ],
            );
          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
```

Comment: "If you want the value to load before showing the page", this is what I want which means not showing anything on the whole page I guess but your example is showing a CircularProgressIndicator instead of a Text, TextField and Switch.
It would feel weird and look weird to have loading icons (CircularProgressIndicators) for all elements which are waiting for a value. I don't know what else could be done.. maybe a splash screen and load everything behind that before showing the elements?
Is there any other way to do this? I would prefer just making the startup time longer before showing ANYTHING

Comment: Just insert your entire screen (Scaffold e.g) in a FutureBuilder and instead of the CircularProgressIndicator just show e.g an image (same image as splash screen maybe) or SizedBox.shrink() to show nothing at all.